# Aggregate Method Not Getting Updated Data MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

So when I make a DELETE request I am updating my model and deleting the selected array item. Then I am sending the updated JSON data back via ajax. I am using the aggregate method to determine the sum of selected values in an array, but the problem is the aggregate method is returning the data based on what is available BEFORE I delete the list item even though I put it in the callback. So how can I get the correct updated sum? Here is the code I am using:

```
regUser.findOneAndUpdate(
    { username:req.user.username },
    { $pull: { budgets : { uniqueId: parseFloat(req.param('id')) }} }, 
    function(err, data){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        regUser.aggregate([
            { $match : { username : req.user.username } },
            // Unwind the array to de-normalize the items
            { "$unwind": "$budgets" },
                // Group the totals with conditions
            { "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "expense": { "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        "$budgets.expense",
                        "$budgets.value",
                        0
                    ]
            }},
                "nonExpense": { "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        "$budgets.expense",
                        0,
                        "$budgets.value"
                    ]
            }}
            }}], function(err, aggData){
                sumData = aggData
        });
        res.json({
            sumData: sumData,
            budgetList: data.budgets
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async programming gotcha :). Move:

```
   res.json({
        sumData: sumData,
        budgetList: data.budgets
    });
```

inside the regUser.aggregate callback function.

```
function(err, aggData){
   res.json({
        sumData: aggData,
        budgetList: data.budgets
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. So why would it work when putting the response inside of the aggregate call back function, but not the way I had it?

Comment: it's the way the Event loop works in Node. The functions are NOT executed when the compiler reads them. they are scheduled, aka added to the event loop list. once that happens the node compiler makes a pass to see who's next at the top of the list to be executed. since it's single thread event loop, only one executes at same time.